# Read Shell Script option separated by space

Tags: shell, sh

I have this shell script:

```
for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -l=*|--ddloc=*)
    DDLOC="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    *)
          # unknown option
    ;;
esac
done
```

Its working fine as `-x=y` but i want to be like `-x y`. What changes will be required here?

Comment: Hava a look at `getopt` or builtin `getopts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -l=*|--ddloc=*)
    DDLOC="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    -l|--ddloc)
    shift # past argument
    DDLOC="$1"
    shift # past value
    ;;
    *)
          # unknown option
    ;;
esac
done
```

Comment: I think this is a syntax error, you miss `;;` before `*)`, right?

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry, yes. Thanks.